# The value specified in the URL Key field would generate a URL that already exists after migration from M1

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool

I have migrated the project from Magento 1 to Magento 2.3.4 everything is working fine.
But In admin when I try to change the category name it shows me error

**The value specified in the URL Key field would generate a URL that already exists.**

Why I am getting this error even if I am changing the category **url key**

**Search Engine Optimization  >> URL KEY**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you restarted your migration after doing it the first time. This could end up in duplicate URL keys.  In a test database I would try removing your rewrite URLS and reindexing to rebuild them.

This should solve your problem.

If that doesn't work you can try migrating to a "Clean database"